# Error with initializing a 2d wide char array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to do a 2d wchar_t array initialization using that code:

```
const wchar_t* e[6][]={
    { L"ç", L"$^^" },
    { L"ç"},
    { L"ç", L"$^^" },
    { L"ç", L"$^^" },
    { L"ç", L"$^^" },
    { L"ç", L"$^^" }
};
```

but I get an error when compiling:

```
array type has incomplete element type
```

so what's wrong and what to do to solve that problem?

Comment: What you are trying to declare isn't a 2D-array to `wchar_t`, but to  **pointers to** `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only optional length when declaring an array is the first one, so in your case you need to specify the second one:

```
const wchar_t *e[][2] ;
```

Moreover be carefull that the array in second position is filled with `NULL` value at the end:

```
{L"ç"} 
// is in fact
{L"ç", NULL}
```

Comment: this array should have different sized lines: so the 2nd line can have a different size.

Comment: @user3457200 It is not possible to create static array with different length for each line in C.

Comment: I tested this array as it was with doing 'const wchar_t *e[][2]' on a test program, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @user3457200 It's because your array is automtically filled with `NULL` value at the end, but its size is still 2.

Comment: @Holt you can omit initializers, it would initialize missing items with a null pointer.

Comment: @Holt ok, I understand, however I have the same error with compiling that 3d array:                                       'const wchar_t *d[][][6]={
            { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
            { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }},
            { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
            { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
            { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } },
            { { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" }, { L"où", L"kjhkh;;" } }
        };'                                                       so what should I do for fixing that?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes I know, see my edit and comment above yours, I only though it would be relevant to add precision, because often beginner think that `[]` is some kind of magic.

Comment: @user3457200 As I said in my answer, you need to specify EACH length except the first one, so in your case you need to put something like `const wchar_t *d[][2][2]` (maybe it's something else than 2, but you get the idea).

Comment: all right, I understand, but I think that 'const wchar_t *d[][2][6]' will be more correct, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are declaring the array is wrong...
You should be doing...

`const wchar_t* e[][6]` instead of  `const wchar_t* e[6][]`